# How to prove this inequality for the given function?

Tags: calculus

Given function $f(x)=x-\log x$. When $a>1$, there are two roots $r_1(a), r_2(a)$ for equation $f(x)=a$.
We also have $0<r_1(a)<1<r_2(a)$. Now given two real numbers $a>1,b>1$, how to prove $f(r_2(a)r_2(b))>f(r_1(a)r_1(b))$?

Comment: Have you tried plug them in?

Answer (score 3):

We have,
\begin{align*}
f(r_2(a) r_2(b)) - f(r_1(a) r_1(b)) & = r_2(a) r_2(b) - \log(r_2(a) r_2(b)) - r_1(a) r_1(b) + \log(r_1(a)r_1(b)) \\
& = r_2(a) r_2(b) - \log(r_2(a)) - \log(r_2(b)) - r_1(a) r_1(b) + \log(r_1(a)) + \log(r_1(b)) \\
& = r_2(a) r_2(b) + a - r_2(a) + b - r_2(b) - r_1(a) r_1(b) + r_1(a) - a + r_1(b)-b \\
& = r_2(a) r_2(b)  - r_2(a) - r_2(b) + 1 - 1 - r_1(a) r_1(b) + r_1(a)  + r_1(b) \\
& = (r_2(a) - 1)(r_2(b) - 1) + (1 - r_1(a))(1 - r_1(b))   \\
& > 0,
\end{align*}
as required.